# Old workflow messages sent

Tags: workflow

We randomly get old workflow messages sent.  Recently many old messages from a single person were resent as "task changed" messages.  It occurs once then again a week or two later.  We are using SP2007

Answer (score 1):

If there are workflows running and an update to the workflow is made and published, the workflows are still operatig under the old version and could have old information like this. If you look at the workflow settings on the list/library, are there old versions of the workflow present and if so does it show any instances of those in progress?